How to write an autocompletion function in bashrc for words from history?
How to write an autocompletion function in bashrc for previously used words (not commands in full) from history?
For example
less firstFile.txt
gvim secondFile.txt

Then suppose we want to autocomplete the word "firstFile.txt" to be used in some other command:
cat firs<press the bound shortcut for the autocomplete function> 

to autocomplete as below:
cat firstFile.txt


It's quite trivial to comb through the output of history split at whitespaces, and return one or more matches. But if you wanted to also find something like first File.txt from a previously entered less 'first File.txt', you'd actually need to parse each entry in the history first, which is considerably more difficult (nested quoting, multi-line entries, …).

which commands do you want to use this "feature"? only for cat? or a few selected commands? and what if there's already a completion spec for these commands? not an easy task obviously. first you need to figure out your real requirements.

'first File.txt' don't need to be considered as a single word. Output of history split at whitespaces can be considered as words.

I want to use this feature irrespective of the commands. "cat" is just an example. In fact ca should autocomplete to cat , if cat is present as the last word starting with "ca" in history.

Here's a rudimentary implementation that extracts the word before the cursor, finds the latest history item that contains that word, and performs the replacement. If there is no match or the match is identical, nothing is replaced. Adapt it to your needs as you see fit (e.g. by employing fzf for a selection, etc.).
Note: This approach simply tokenizes the history by replacing occurrences of $IFS with newlines. Thus, firstFile.txt could be found while first File.txt would not. In this comment, you've stated:

'first File.txt' don't need to be considered as a single word. Output of history split at whitespaces can be considered as words.

#!/bin/bash

complete_from_history() {

  # Extract parts of the command line
  local beforecursor="${READLINE_LINE::READLINE_POINT}"
  local aftercursor="${READLINE_LINE:READLINE_POINT}"
  local lastword="${beforecursor##* }"
  local beforeword="${beforecursor%"$lastword"}"

  # Find a match in the history
  newword="$(history -w /dev/stdout | tac | tr "$IFS" "\n" | grep -Fm1 "$lastword")"
  newword="${newword:-$lastword}"

  # Update command line and cursor position
  READLINE_LINE="$beforeword$newword$aftercursor"
  READLINE_POINT=$((READLINE_POINT + ${#newword} - ${#lastword}))

}

# Bind Alt-h to this function
bind -x '"\eh": complete_from_history'

Source this script, then type something, and press Alt+h.
